# Qual è il significato di "intrufagnito"?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives, regional

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Contratta sulla sedia peggio di un merluzzo essicato, Gheri non aveva proferito mezza sillaba, non aveva mosso mezzo muscolo facciale. In compenso, proprio mentre la zia canterina si esibiva, s'era alzata da tavola di botto, senza chiedere permesso. Ed era tornata poi ancora piú *intrufagnita*, se possibile, piú scura, intorbidata, aggrovigliata.

Ho cercato il significato di "intrufagnito", ma non l'ho trovato. Dal contesto, immagino che abbia qualcosa a che vedere con "essere di cattivo umore". Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Secondo me, 'sta scrittrice è una cui piace condire i periodi di parole inutili. Forse, così, crede di sfoggiare maggior talento.

Comment: Come nell'altra tua domanda sul  "babacetto",  sembra che la scrittrice faccia uso di termini di origine dialettale. Questo in particolare non si trova  nei dizionari dialettali.  Tieni conto che i dialetti in Italia hanno moltissime varianti locali, a volte i termini possono essere diversi da paese a paese per cui è difficile  che siano registrati tutti. È lo stesso in Spagna?

Comment: @Josh61: Nel parlato ci sono parole appartenenti a varietà dialettali del castigliano e del catalano che non sempre si trovano nei dizionari, ma non sono sicura su cosa succede nello scritto.

Comment: @Elberich: Se non ti piace, sei completamente libero di non leggere i libri di questa scrittrice. Se è come dice Josh61, sono davvero contenta perché questa lettura mi dà l'opportunità di "ascoltare" un po' dell'italiano che si parla a Torino.

Comment: @Charo - I dialetti in Italia sono molto importanti da un punto di vista culturale, e famose  opere letterarie sono in dialetto (il teatro di Goldoni ad esempio). L'uso di termini dialettali nella lingua italiana è comune e alcuni termini sono noti  a livello nazionale. Mi viene in mente la 'sola' romana, ma ce ne sono molti altri. Se a questo unisci il fatto degli 'inglesismi' il risultato e' un interessante "melting pot' :)

Comment: Giusto per precisare: non tutte le opere di Goldoni sono in veneto. Ad esempio *La locandiera* (ambientato a Firenze se non mi sbaglio) è in italiano, mentre *I rusteghi* è quasi completamente in veneto (tranne il personaggio del cavaliere "foresto")

Comment: La letteratura del Veneto è notoriamente una delle più ricche dal punto di vista della gamma e del rilievo dell'uso "riflesso" del "dialetto", o meglio dei "dialetti". Soprattutto nella straordinaria densità e rilievo della sua letteratura teatrale, da Ruzante a Calmo e Giancarli, dalla fitta e meno nota schiera degli autori del Seicento, da Goldoni a Gozzi, da Selvatico a Gallina, da Simoni a Rocca a Palmieri, per limitarsi a pochi nomi. http://www.accademiateatroveneto.it/corsi-recitazione-dialetto-veneto.php

Comment: @DenisNardin:  A me hanno detto che *La Locandiera* è in toscano che poi è diventato italiano standard.

Comment: @Charo Sì, è vero, sono stato un po' impreciso

Comment: Certo che per essere sconosciuto ai motori di ricerca direi che più che termine dialettale torinese è una vera e propria invenzione dell'autore. Forse lega il significato ad un certo senso onomatopeico del suono della parola.

Comment: ho cercato anche qui: pms.wikipedia.org (la wiki piemontese) ma non hanno censito il termine, quindi non so se è dialettale (la Mastrocola è nata a Torino(

Comment: Sono daccordo con Elberich sul fatto che la scrittrice si dia delle arie farcendo di parole in disuso i suoi libri. Mi sono chiesto molte volte se la gran quantitá di domande sui libri di questa scrittrice sconosciuta siano in realtá pubblicitá occulta.

Comment: @JoeTaras: La Wikipedia, piemontese o no che sia, è un'enciclopedia, non un dizionario. Quindi anche se questo fosse un termine dialettale comunissimo non risulterebbe lo stesso. Tu o qualcun altro ha per caso accesso a un dizionario dialettale piemontese?

Comment: @Bruno9779 e altri: Ci sono anche molte domande su Calvino e altri autori: tutta pubblicità occulta? Quanto al fatto di usare termini dialettali e più o meno inventati, non è esattamente la prima volta che succede in un libro. Per la sola Italia e solo negli ultimi decenni, ci sono decine di autori che lo fanno, da Gadda a Camilleri. Come è stato già detto: se non vi piacciono, nessuno vi obbliga a leggerli. Stroncare, o anche solo dare dello “sconosciuto” tout court, a un autore che non si conosce non è molto costruttivo, no?

Comment: Calvino é quasi un classico e viene insegnato nelle scuole da piú di trent'anni. Il paragone non regge

Comment: @Bruno9779 e altri: Questo romanzo mi è stato raccomandato da un'italiana esperta in letteratura.

Comment: @Bruno9779: Effettivamente mi sono spiegato male. Non era un paragone, facevo notare che le stesse persone fanno domande su vari autori, via via che capita loro di leggerli: un giorno è Calvino, un altro è la Mastrocola.

Comment: @Bruno9779 - pubblicità occulta ad un autore per il fatto che usa termini dialettali non sempre comprensibili? Piuttosto insolita come strategia di marketing.

Comment: @DaG - questa lista di termini dialettali è quanto sono riuscito a trovare: http://protorino.altervista.org/pdf/piemontese-base.pdf . È stata utile per il termine 'babacetto', ma non trovo nulla su questo, che a me sembra una storpiatura o un uso locale di qualche altro termine.

Comment: Grazie, @Josh61.

Comment: @DaG: [Qui](http://www.cumpagniadiventemigliusi.it/Elaborati/Indice.htm) appare "strufugnà" col significato di "gualcire". Potrebbe riferirsi all'espressione del viso? E [qui](https://archive.org/stream/dellidiomaedell00randgoog/dellidiomaedell00randgoog_djvu.txt) ci sono le parole "strufugià" e "strufuggiun".

Answer (score 2):

Pur essendo di Torino, non conosco questo termine. Sicuramente "suona" piemontese (in dialetto sarebbe " 'ntrufagnì "), e che ad orecchio lo renderei in italiano con "ingrugnito". Si tratta di un termine che, anche se inesistente o desueto, evoca comunque l'idea dell'espressione ingrugnita a chiunque conosca il dialetto piemontese.

Comment: Potrebbe avere qualcosa a che vedere col termine "trugnu" che appare [qui](http://protorino.altervista.org/pdf/piemontese-base.pdf)?

Comment: Secondo me, solo come suono. Se si vuole un aggettivo dello stesso significato di "intrufagnito", e che deriva da "trugnu", si dice "intrugnito", che è molto più frequente dell'altro e direi universalmente compreso dai piemontesi.

Comment: Se è così, probabilmente sia come dice @Josh61, cioè, che si tratti di una storpiatura o di un uso locale del termine "intrugnita".