# Cosa significa "sverso"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Avessero potuto, l'avrebbero fatta in briciole quella loro figlia, che era cosí da quando era nata: musona, indispettita, critica, scettica, cinica. Che brutto carattere. Sempre *sversa* col mondo intero. Sempre a criticare.

La mia domanda è sulla parola "sversa" nel brano precedente.  Ha qualcosa a che vedere col verbo ["sversare"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sversare_res-47000c52-89ed-11e8-a7cb-00271042e8d9_(Neologismi))? O si tratta anche questo di un vocabolo di origine dialettale? Nella [lista di termini dialettali piemontesi](http://protorino.altervista.org/pdf/piemontese-base.pdf) trovata da @Josh61 appare "svers" col significato di "sconvolto", ma non so se questo significato abbia molto senso in questo contesto. Qualcuno sa dirmi cosa significa esattamente?

Comment: Adesso so che la Mastrocola non piace ad alcuni degli utenti di questo sito, ma io voglio fare questo tipo di domande lo stesso. Mi aiutano ad approfondire la mia lettura.

Comment: Un altro significato popolare di sverso, in Piemonte è ubriaco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Sversa" è, come intuito da Charo, un vocabolo di origine dialettale piemontese. In Piemonte è un aggettivo molto comune, che indica uno stato d'animo *temporaneo*. Si può rendere con "musona, di malumore, contrariata". Ma è essenziale capire che si tratta di una condizione passeggera. Non a caso nel testo di Matrocola è preceduta da "sempre". In Piemonte non si descrive una persona dicendo che "è sversa". Si dice che "oggi è sversa", o "è spesso sversa", o "è sempre sversa".

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @enrico, e grazie mille della risposta! Ne sapresti qualcosa su quest'altra domanda: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/6326/qual-%c3%a8-il-significato-di-intrufagnito?

Comment: Grazie Charo. Essendo nuovo non capisco se risponere qui all'altra domanda (e non ho una vera e propria risposta). Dove devo scriverla e in quale forma?

Comment: Non devi rispondere qui.  Esegui il link della domanda e scrivi la tua risposta nel quadro col titolo "Your answer".

Comment: Manca la dimostrazione che sia di origine piemontese. La risposta di @DaG, che fa uso del Devoto-Oli, non lo menziona. Hai fonti?

Comment: Ho trovato la conferma che mancava in [questo articolo](https://dial.uclouvain.be/downloader/downloader.php?pid=boreal:81491&datastream=PDF_01) e leggendo il romanzo *La malora* di Beppe Fenoglio.

Comment: Da *La malora* di Beppe Fenoglio: «Sentite, Braida, io ho l’anima sversa perché oggi m’è venuta una donna dei Bragioli a portarmi le robiole e gliene ho pagate dodici e adesso ho visto che erano solo undici. Non è il piú bel momento per burlare.»

Answer (score 6):

Vedo che è assente da molti dizionari, ma c'è per esempio sul Devoto-Oli (cartaceo, edizione 1990): «Stravolto, in subbuglio: *Sentite, Braida, io ho l'anima sversa perché oggi...* (Fenoglio) [tratto da *sversato*]», il che pare confermare quel repertorio di termini piemontesi.

*Sversato*, a sua volta, è dato come «Goffo» o «Sgarbato, sguaiato, sgraziato».

Personalmente (Italia centrale) ho sentito di rado il termine e non lo uso, ma mi avrebbe dato più l'idea di significare “di malumore, scontroso, contrariato” o simili, che sembra anche più pertinente nel brano citato.

Comment: La citazione di Fenoglio è dal romanzo *La malora*.

Comment: Secondo [questo articolo](https://dial.uclouvain.be/downloader/downloader.php?pid=boreal:81491&datastream=PDF_01) il significato di "sversa" è "contrariata".

Comment: «L’influsso 
del dialetto ha lasciato delle tracce anche nel lessico de *La malora*; Fenoglio utilizza 
“censa” invece di “privativa”, “stroppo” invece di “branco”, “onta” invece di “vergogna”, 
“particolare” invece di “piccolo possidente”, “bricco” invece di “monte”, “rubarizio” invece di “furto”, “diffizioso” invece di “schizzinoso”, “sversa” invece di “contrariata”, “alla mira” invece di “al punto”, “genare” invece di “imbarazzare”, “schivare” invece di “tener da parte” e “sbardati” invece di “sparpagliati” (tutti questi esempi secondo Grignani, 97).»

Answer (score 2):

La risposta di DaG è corretta: anzi in Toscana (Firenze, Pisa, Livorno) è proprio presente il termine *inversato*, nel significato di "contrariato, scontroso", da "verso" nel significato di *direzione*.

C'è però una ambiguità perché il sostantivo *sverso* è proprio collegato al verbo *sversare* (anche se in genere si usa il termine *sversamento*): *sverso di liquidi inquinanti*, *non è consentito lo sverso...*.

Answer (score 2):

Come ha spiegato @enrico nella sua risposta, il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000624.jpg) riporta "sverso" come termine proveniente dal piemontese "svers". Ecco la definizione di questo aggettivo che dà questo vocabolario:

> **Ṣvèrso,** agg. Region.  Profondamente turbato, addo­lorato, o anche seccato, infastidito. 
>         *Fenoglio*, 2-220:  Io  ho  l’anima  sversa  perché  oggi  m’è  venuta 
>   una  donna  dei  Bragioli  a  portarmi  le  robiole  e  gliene  ho  pagate dodici e adesso ho visto che erano solo undici. 
>         = Dal piemont. *svers* propr. ‘rovesciato’.