# Differenza tra le marche d'uso "reg." e "dial." dei dizionari italiani

Tags: word-meaning, difference

I dizionari italiani, come, per esempio, il vocabolario Treccani, il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* o lo Zingarelli, fanno uso dei termini "regionalismo" (di solito abbreviato "reg."), "dialettalismo" (usualmente abbreviato "dial.") e a volte anche abbreviazioni più esplicite come "sett.",  “centrosett.”, "sicil.", ecc. per segnalare alcune voci o determinate accezioni di alcune voci. Non mi è per niente  chiaro, però, cosa si intenda esattamente per "regionalismo" e per "dialettalismo": qual è la differenza tra questi due termini? A volte ho avuto la sensazione, per quello che ho letto in qualche commento, che con "dialettalismo" si volesse indicare un vocabolo di uso ancora più ristretto, cioè, un termine il cui significato non è noto agli italiani che non conoscono un determinato dialetto o che è sentito come "scorretto" ([ecco un esempio](https://www.corriere.it/scuola/universita/cards/ceretta-linguine-cortelli-affilatigli-errori-grammatica-piu-comuni/cortello-parte-manico.shtml)) nel senso che alcune persone lo percepiscono come non propriamente italiano, di quello che si fa con un regionalismo, ma forse questa è una sensazione completamente sbagliata.

Nel documento [*L'italiano del XXI secolo. Manualetto per studenti stranieri*](https://www.academia.edu/38040465/Litaliano_del_XXI_secolo_Manualetto_per_studenti_stranieri), di Sabina Gola (Université libre de Bruxelles), ho trovato queste definizioni:

> Regionalismi: parole usate soprattutto nella zona d’origine

> Dialettismi: parole che hanno superato i confini locali e si sono diffuse in tutta la penisola perché associati a particolari prodotti o fenomeni

Infatti, queste definizioni sono un riassunto di quello che è esposto in [*Grammatica italiana con nozioni di linguistica*](https://www.academia.edu/28739901/GRAMMATICA_ITALIANA) di Maurizio Dardano and Pietro Trifone.

Per quanto concerne i dialettalismi, questo libro spiega:

> I nostri dialetti hanno contribuito alla formazione dell'italiano fin dai primi tempi:
>   *arsenale* e *lido* vengono da Venezia; *scoglio*, *prua* e *darsena* da Genova; *ammainare* da Napoli; *portolano* da Palermo. Nel diciottesimo secolo la Lombardia ha
>   dato il *calmiere*, Napoli la *lava* e la *mofeta*, termini relativi ai fenomeni vulcanici. 
>         Per entrare nel lessico italiano i **dialettalismi** devono italianizzarsi nella forma: così *l'arzanà de' Viniziani* ricordato da Dante (*Inferno*, XXI, 7) è diventato
>   l'*arsenale*. Nell'ultimo dopoguerra il settentrionale *imbranà* ha preso un suffisso
>   italiano diventando *imbranato*.
>   In quali settori si attinge al lessico dei dialetti? Due sono le categorie principali di
>   dialettalismi:
>
> - termini tecnici (prodotti regionali tipici, agricoltura, allevamento, caratteri ambientali, nomenclature di vario tipo);
> - parole espressive relative a situazioni, a costumi, ad atti che si prestano
>     alla rappresentazione parodistica e allo scherzo.
>
> Per quanto riguarda la prima di queste due categorie ricordiamo che già nell'Ottocento la *filanda* lombarda s'impone sul *filatoio* fiorentino: più tardi in luogo dei
>   fiorentini *ammazzatoio*, *mezzaiolo*, *mezzeria*, *marcitoia* si preferiscono: *mattatoio* (Roma e Italia centrale), *mezzadro* e *mezzadria* (Emilia), *marcita* 'terreno irrigato anche d'inverno' (Lombardia). Abbiamo già parlato del successo dei settentrionali *lavello* e *scocca*. 
>   Segnaliamo altri prestiti dai dialetti, distinguendo per regione: 
>         da Genova vengono: *abbaino*, *acciuga*, *mugugno*;
>   
>         dalla Lombardia: *balera*, *barbone*, *brughiera*, *gorgonzola*, *grana*, *metronotte*,
>   *panettone*, *risotto*;
>         dal Piemonte: *arrangiarsi* (passato nell'italiano popolare: v. 16.6), *cicchetto* (diffuso con il gergo militare), *fonduta*, *gianduiotto* e *grissino*;
>   
>         da Roma: *bocce*, *caciara*, *cocciuto*, *dritto* 'furbo', *fanatico* 'ostentatore', *pappagallo* 'corteggiatore', *pizzardone* 'vigile urbano';
>   
>         sono di area romanesca e napoletana: *fasullo*, *racchio*, *scippo*, *stronzo*, *tardona*;
>   
>         da Napoli vengono: *camorra*, *iella*, *omertà*, *spocchia*;
>   
>         dalla Sicilia: *mafia* e *intrallazzo*.

Ed ecco la spiegazione che riguarda i regionalismi del libro sopra menzionato:

> Le varietà regionali di italiano (v. 2.1.2) differiscono tra loro anche nel lessico.
>   L'*anguria* del Nord diventa *cocomero* nel Centro, *melone* o *mellone* nel Sud; in Toscana e nel Sud si ha *cacio*, nel Nord *formaggio*; alle *caldarroste* di Roma corrispondono altrove le *castagne arrostite*; il *prezzemolo* si chiama *erborino* in Lombardia e *petrosino* in Sicilia; i *lacci* delle scarpe sono denominati anche, secondo
>   le regioni, *legacci*, *laccetti*, *stringhe*, *aghetti*. Questo tipo di regionalismi lessicali
>   si chiamano **geosinonimi**, come dire 'sinonimi geografici': secondo le regioni si indica la stessa cosa con un nome diverso. 
>   Lo studio dei **regionalismi** lessicali non è facile. Infatti ci sono vocaboli comuni a ciascuna delle quattro varietà di italiano regionale che abbiamo già distinto (settentrionale, toscana, romana, meridionale), ma poi vi sono vocaboli propri dell'italiano della Lombardia, dell'italiano dell'Emilia, dell'italiano della Sicilia ecc. 
>   [...]

Seguono un elenco di esempi di regionalismi e alcune considerazioni e riflessioni sul fenomeno dei regionalismi lessicali nell'italiano moderno.

Tuttavia, non sono sicura che queste spiegazioni si corrispondano con quello che intendono i dizionari quando marcano i lemmi con questi termini. Le definizioni che ne dà il Treccani ([1](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/regionalismo) e [2](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dialettalismo)) sono queste:

> **regionalismo** [...] In linguistica, termine, locuzione o costruzione sintattica proprî di una determinata regione.
>
> **dialettalismo** [...] Vocabolo, espressione o forma di origine dialettale; variante fonetica di natura dialettale. Anche *dialettismo*.

Bene: questo si capisce, ma penso che molti dei regionalismi nel senso della definizione precedente siano anche dei dialettalismi. E, a quanto pare (non ho fatto un controllo esaustivo), gli esempi di dialettalismi del libro di Dardano e Trifone non sono marcati con "dial." nei vocabolari. Per queste ragioni  non mi è chiara la distinzione che se ne fa nei dizionari. Me la sapreste spiegare?

Per esempio, come si spiegava in questa [risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/11425/), il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* dà
 "sverso" come regionalismo, ma spiega anche che provviene del piemontese "svers", quindi, in questo senso,  sarebbe anche un dialettalismo. Invece, questo stesso dizionario dà, per esempio, i vocaboli  ["diacciera"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI04/00000319.jpg) e ["bavarola"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000133.jpg) come dialettalismi e indica che si tratta di una voce toscana il primo e di una voce romanesca il secondo. Capisco che, come ha detto @DaG in un suo commento, quando il dizionario indica che un termine di origine dialettale è un regionalismo, s'intenda che sia entrato a far parte dell'italiano regionale di una certa zona geografica. Allora, prendendo uno degli esempi precedenti, se "bavarola" è un dialettalismo ma non è un regionalismo, cioè, non è entrato a far parte dell'[italiano regionale di Roma](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/italiano-di-roma_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/), significa che ha un uso più ristretto, cioè, che si trova soltanto nell'italiano di alcune persone (come Moravia) che l'adoperano per influenza del romanesco?

Comment: Ora non posso consultare i miei libri, ma mi risulta che, in sociolinguistica, "italiano regionale" e "dialetto" siano due livelli standard, ben distinti.

Comment: Sì, @DaG, ma penso che "dialetto" e "dialettalismo" siano due cose diverse. Per esempio, il GDLI dà [*sverso*](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/11425/) come regionalismo, ma spiega anche che provviene del piemontese "svers": in questo senso sarebbe anche un dialettalismo, no? Invece, questo stesso dizionario dà *acquacotta* o *bedana* come dialettalismi.

Comment: Dire che in Italia ogni regione ha il suo dialetto, e viceversa, non è accurato, ma neanche del tutto sbagliato. In una regione si possono parlare due o tre dialetti, diversi, che però hanno in comune qualche termine regionale (magari il nome di un piatto tipico). Forse, chi scrive un dizionario, sceglie *regionale* o *dialettale* secondo la sensazione che  il termine sia legato a un singolo dialetto o a una singola regione. Però mi pare una sottigliezza e a me i due termini paiono abbastanza intercambiabili.

Comment: Più si entra nel campo della sociolinguistica, più si esce dalla linguistica. La sociolonguistica opera con classificazioni arbitrarie di fenomeni e, a mio avviso, è molto simile alla sociologia come "soft science".

Comment: Quello che intendevo, @Charo, è che dialettismo sta a dialetto come regionalismo sta a italiano regionale. Non so niente del piemontese, ma da quello che trascrivi parrebbe che "sverso" sia entrato nell'italiano regionale del Piemonte.

Comment: Dai, @Nico e linuxfan: non posso credere a quello che state dicendo. Penso che in questi dizionari si sia fatto un lavoro troppo serio per poi finire aggiungendo queste qualifiche in modo arbitrario o secondo le sensazioni di una persona.

Comment: Non intendevo che si fosse lavorato male, ma che la sociolinguistica, a differenza di altri rami linguistici, presenta maggiore arbitrarietà di classificazione che dipendono dalla scuola di pensiero. "Arbitrarietà" era forse improprio. Intendevo "opinioni molto disparate".

Comment: @Nico:  Quindi, secondo te, i criteri per aggiungere queste marche nelle entrate dei vocabolari 
possono essere molto diversi tra un dizionario e un altro?

Comment: Argomentando dal punto di vista di un linguista, sì. Ci sono scale di dimostrabilità diverse a seconda del ramo. Ora, in sintassi non ci sono dissensi. Un sintagma nominale come "un bel cane" rimane un sintagma nominale. Questo vale anche per la fonologia. La semantica, invece, presenta già più punti controversi riguardo per esempio a fenomeni come la sinonimia. Ancora più controversa è la classificazione pragmatica dei "discourse markers". La sociolinguistica, a mio avviso, è al polo opposto della sintassi per quanto riguarda un consenso più o meno generale.

Answer (score 2):

Ecco la spiegazione che appare nella sezione ["Marca d'uso"](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/avvertenze/6) del dizionario De Mauro:

> **RE**: regionale; sono vocaboli, in parte, ma non necessariamente, di provenienza dialettale, usati soprattutto in una delle varietà regionali dell’italiano, specificate di seguito in forma abbreviata; 
>   **DI**: dialettale; sono così marcati vocaboli avvertiti come dialettali e circolanti in quanto tali in testi e discorsi italiani, con indicazione abbreviata del dialetto;

Quindi, molti "regionalismi" sono di provenienza dialettale (cioè, sono anche "dialettalismi"), ma non tutti. Come indicava @DaG in un suo commento, quello che fa la differenza tra un "regionalismo" di origine dialettale e un vocabolo indicato nel dizionario come "dial." (che forse sta per "dialettale" e non per "dialettalismo") è se il vocabolo è o non è usato in una varietà regionale dell'italiano: nel primo caso è qualificato come "reg." ("RE" nel De Mauro) o, in modo più specifico, "sett.", “centrosett.”, "sicil.", ecc. I vocaboli marcati come "dial." ("DI" nel De Mauro), invece, non sono usati in modo generalizzato in una varietà regionale dell'italiano, ma si possono rintracciare in testi e discorsi in italiano. Quindi, in questo senso, hanno un uso più ristretto nella lingua italiana.

Comment: L'ho messo come risposta perché è l'unica spiegazione che sono riuscita a trovare su questo argomento. Se, però, qualcuno di voi riesce a dare qualche informazione in più, sarà benvenuta. (Ma, per carità, non mi dire che si tratta di qualifiche arbitrarie o basate sulle sensazioni di qualcuno :).

Comment: Non lo dico per impuntarmi, ma considera che in Veneto si parla il veneto, in Piemonte il piemontese, in Calabria il calabrese, in Sicilia il siciliano eccetera. Il confine tra dialettalismo e "regionalismo" è sottile e ambiguo, e anche mettendoci buona volontà il risultato di una catalogazione rimane dibattibile. Ci possono essere eccezioni, certamente. segue...

Comment: ...E poi c'è l'altro problema: poniamo che un Umberto Eco qualsiasi metta un vocabolo dialettale (o regionale?) in un suo libro: subito qualche linguista (o redattore di dizionari...) va a pensare che il vocabolo è "italiano" perchè l'ha usato il grande e "autorevole" Umberto Eco, riconoscendo magari che quel vocabolo in Lazio non lo capiscono, e allora diventa "regionale" (perchè pare che lo capiscano solo in Piemonte Lombardia e Liguria).

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Sì, ma qui non stiamo parlando di dialetto, ma di dialettalismi presenti nella lingua italiana. È qualcosa simile a quando in castigliano si usa una parola di origine catalana.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Riguardo al tuo secondo commento, non è questo il criterio che si segue quando si elabora un dizionario.

Answer (score -1):

Dico subito che questa risposta è una mia idea personale, come lo sono d'altra parte altre risposte su questo sito.

Vado con ordine: trovo azzardato prendere una parola dialettale, o di origine dialettale, o "regionale", insomma limitata nell'uso, e dichiararla appartenente alla lingua italiana. Chi può dire se una parola appartiene alla nostra lingua o no? Ci sarebbe un'autorità che non cito, oppure si potrebbe prendere la percentuale di persone che usano e capiscono la parola. Un 80% dei parlanti italiano? Forse meglio un 50%? Un 10%? Quanto?

Passo ai vocabolari. L'interesse di un vocabolario è riportare, ragionevolmente, quante più voci possibile, compatibilmente con il costo dell'opera. Il vocabolario non dice se o quanto una parola risieda legittimamente in mezzo alle altre, non è quello il suo scopo: deve limitarsi a marcare certe parole come "rare", "obsolete", "antiquate", "dialettali". Perché? Perché se un certo dizionario non comprende una certa parola, può venir percepito incompleto - allora è meglio inserirla! Ma se cita una parola troppo rara, troppo delimitata territorialmente, senza annotarla, potrebbe venir percepito come inaccurato o facilone.

Credo che un vocabolario completo anche di parole rare sia utile a chiunque lo consulti. Ma, ripeto, il fatto che un certo termine si trovi in un vocabolario non lo qualifica automaticamente come appartenente alla lingua italiana. Altri dizionari potrebbero non citare quel termine (sto parlando di *cachinnare*, di *sverso* e cose simili). Ed è vero anche il contrario: se un vocabolario non cita una certa parola, non vuol dire che non esiste.

Nei commenti ho anche detto che, a volte, uno scrittore (anche autorevole, bravissimo, immenso) può usare un termine dialettale o regionale in un suo scritto, ma questo non vuol dire che quella parola appartenga all'italiano. Ma qualcun altro (il redattore di un dizionario) magari pensa che quel termine vada incluso nel dizionario, perché se lo scrittore l'ha usato, allora il termine esiste; oppure perché tante persone leggeranno quell'autore, e allora... il dizionario sarà utile a coloro!

Detto questo, dico che, anche alla luce di quanto sopra, fare distinzione fra *dialettale* e *regionale* è difficile, comunque ambiguo, opinabile, e in certi casi pure errato. È sicuramente difficile perché l'Italia è divisa in regioni, e praticamente ogni regione ha il suo dialetto. Vi sono eccezioni, ma in Piemonte si parla piemontese, in Liguria il ligure, in Sardegna il sardo, in Puglia il pugliese, eccetera. E allora, in molti casi, che differenza c'è fra termine dialettale e regionale?
 Prendiamo "sverso", parola che conosco molto bene. È dialettale, sicuramente. È regionale, sicuramente, perché tutti quelli che parlano piemontese sono in Piemonte! A parte un distaccamento in Calabria. Ma può un dizionario perdersi in distinzioni, in un caso come questo? Secondo me no, per cui il redattore sceglierà  una delle due qualifiche.

Credo che sia irragionevole pensare alla linguistica come una scienza esatta, solo la matematica lo è. Una lingua cambia nel tempo, nei luoghi e negli animi; con la lingua si scrivono opere d'arte. Ci sono mode linguistiche che arrivano e passano prima che gli studiosi se ne accorgano; ci sono, in una lingua, cose inspiegabili, altre che *sarebbero* spiegabili ma si sono perse le tracce. Allora gli studiosi si applicano usando metodi, criteri, sensibilità personale (impossibile farne a meno); a volte gli studiosi sono in disaccordo (succede perfino nella matematica, che non è un'opinione). Detto questo: quanta autorevolezza o affidabilità possono avere i linguisti, i dizionari e tutto il resto? Non poca, no; ma neppure il 100%. Forse il 99%, il 90, l'80? Ma neppure una singola percentuale può essere giusta per tutti i lemmi contenuti in un dizionario o per tutte le idee (o i metodi, o i criteri) che può avere un linguista, o il redattore di un dizionario che immagino faccia molto copia e incolla da fonti legittime e (legalmente parlando) illegittime.

Credo di aver terminato la risposta, anche se ci sarebbe molto da aggiungere.

***************** AGGIUNTA DOPO I COMMENTI *************

Ho meditato a lungo prima di scrivere queste precisazioni: non stavano nei commenti, non volevo allungare una risposta già lunga, ma alla fine scrivo qui perchè servono a migliorare la riposta, per pessima che possa essere. E poi, perchè questa risposta è diretta specialmente alla domanda e i suoi commenti, e a chi l'ha posta.

La risposta comincia chiarendo che sono idee personali, e non mi pare che ciò sia il preambolo tipico di chi sale in cattedra.

L'intenzione era andare all'estremo opposto del modo solito di rispondere a Charo: dire qualcosa e citare fonti per far vedere che non è un'invenzione. Lo scopo è far vedere l'altro lato della medaglia, quello opposto a quello che dicono i dizionari. Da 50 anni ho l'Italiano nelle orecchie, e per 20 ho girato l'Italia.
E ho imparato che da regione a regione cambiano l'accento, le parole, il significato di certe parole, il modo di costruire le frasi, il meccanismo dietro al parlare. E aggiungo che scrivere e parlare sono due cose diverse: l'atteggiamento cambia.
Ma un dizionario non può cogliere e trasmettere tutto questo, sarebbe un poema, e infatti esistono libri specializzati su questi aspetti. Ancora, i dizionari possono benissimo contraddirsi, perchè la materia è complessa, incerta e mutevole.
Se, in situazioni delicate, si cercano conferme tra varie fonti, il rischio è d'ingarbugliare ancor più le cose: questa stessa pagina web lo mostra.

Non sono l'unico a pensare questo, ed ecco alcune prove, raccolte nel giro di pochi minuti (non ho molto tempo):

Fonte: Charo stessa:
  ...gli esempi di dialettalismi del libro di Dardano e Trifone **non sono marcati con "dial." nei vocabolari**.
  ...GDLI dice che "sverso" è **regionalismo, ma proviene dal piemontese**
  ...libro Grammatica italiana con nozioni di linguistica: Lo studio dei regionalismi lessicali **non è facile**
    [è un vanto o una liberatoria?]
  ...Charo chiede a Nico se secondo lui le marche su una parola possono essere molto diverse tra un dizionario e l'altro, e lui dice di sì: Più si entra nel campo della sociolinguistica, **più si esce dalla linguistica**

Fonte https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Il_Devoto-Oli
  ...uno dei migliori dizionari italiani...
  ...Sono segnalate 10.000 parole del lessico di base, cioè quelle parole che, **secondo i curatori**...
  ...Nelle nove edizioni dal 2004 al 2014 molte parole sono state retrodatate, **in quanto si è scoperto che**...
  ...registra gli alterati sulla base di testi reali, disponibili in rete (di qui emergono forme generalmente **non inventariate dai lessici** ma ben radicate nell'uso...
  ...Come in altri dizionari dell'uso, **manca quasi sempre, per ragioni di spazio,** ...

Fonte https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dizionario
  ...possono presentare un certo margine di differenza gli uni dagli altri, a seconda del **criterio di scelta iniziale**, che può privilegiare o respingere determinati settori di lingua, con **variazioni individuali** rispetto all'accoglimento...
  ...Nei dizionari **i lessicografi accolgono o rifiutano** le nuove entrate valutando ogni volta l'opportunità...
  ...Un discorso analogo vale per i regionalismi, **presenti, in misura diversa**, nelle varie edizioni dei dizionari, con **scelte e preferenze talvolta** determinate dalla provenienza geografica dei redattori dell'opera
     [quest'ultima affermazione mi pare più grave dell'accusare i redattori di fare copia/incolla]

A scanso di equivoci: così come consiglio a Charo di non fidarsi ciecamente dei dizionari, io stesso non mi fido ciecamente di wikipedia. Ma, in entrambi casi, il non fidarsi non significa non avvalersene.

Vengo al dunque su regionalismi e dialettalismi. Il significato delle due parole è chiarissimo, non serve un dizionario per capirlo (ho controllato, i dizionari concordano). Però Charo, rispondendosi da sola, preleva la spiegazione della marca d'uso dal dizionario De Mauro, e tenta di usarla come definizione generale.
Attenzione Charo, il dominio è diverso: quella spiegazione non definisce il vocabolo in sè, chiarisce come è usato il vocabolo all'interno del dizionario. Difatti la spiegazione è più sfumata rispetto a una definizione:

RE: regionale; sono vocaboli, in parte, ma non necessariamente, di provenienza dialettale, usati soprattutto in una delle varietà regionali...
[Vedi quante clausole limitanti hanno usato, rispetto alla definizione formale del termine?]

DI: dialettale; sono così marcati vocaboli avvertiti come dialettali e circolanti in quanto tali in testi e discorsi italiani...
[Quell'*avvertiti* mi fa suonare l'allarme. Avvertiti da chi? Ma non dovrebbe essere il dizionario stesso a definire con autorevolezza se un vocabolo è un dialettismo o no?]

Ancora: regionale e regionalismo (e dialettale/dialettalismo) non sono esattamente la stessa parola. E' una complicazione in più.

Insomma, i dizionari hanno una certa dose di arbitrarietà. E questa cosa non è negativa, è semplicemente obbligatoria. Inoltre, il termine arbitrario non implica automaticamente significati negativi, indica che si è operata una scelta. Il pi greco non è arbitrario, perchè non si può scegliere e si può descrivere in un modo solo. L'Italiano invece è figlio di alcune scelte decisamente arbitrarie, a partire da colui che decise
di sciacquare i panni in Arno invece che in Tevere, tanto per dirne una, e ce ne sono alcune altre.

Quindi, tornando in tema, la mia tesi è che regionalismo e dialettalismo hanno confini ambigui. Non mi riferisco
a tutti i termini, solo ad alcuni di essi, perché moltissimi termini perfettamente e puramente italiani potrebbero
essere marcati come dialettalismi, l'italiano è un volgare molto arricchito di dialettalismi. L'ambiguità è anche determinata dall'ambito diverso delle due parole: dialettalismo si riferisce a una parlata, mentre regionalismo si riferisce alla geografia. Se gli ambiti sono diversi, è ben possibile che si sovrappongano, originando così quattro combinazioni possibili: termini normali, termini dialettali, termini regionali, termini insieme
dialettali e regionali. Con tutte le sfumature del caso.

Sono vittima, come i dizionari, del poco tempo e poco spazio. Mi fermo qui.

Comment: Secondo questo criterio molte delle domande che si sono fatte su questo sito sarebbero off-topic.

Comment: @Charo, credo che sia vero il contrario! E lo dimostri tu stessa con le domande che posti frequentemente. Se bastasse prendere il dizionario più autorevole per avere LA risposta al 100% corretta e inconfutabile, questo sito non avrebbe senso.  E aggiungo: se le uniche risposte, qui considerate valide, fossero copiate verbatim da un dizionario, allora che gusto ci sarebbe a fornire risposte? segue...

Comment: ... Vedo che tu frequenti siti anche più tecnici (Ubuntu), dove è molto più probabile incontrare l'acronimo RTFM, che su questo sito non ho ancora visto: perchè l'Italiano è molto più complesso, non è standardizzabile da un comitato come l'ISO e, se anche lo fosse in teoria, in una lingua parlata vige un'anarchia assente in ambiti tecnici. Chi redige un programma per computer cerca di adeguarsi alle buone regole, chi scrive un libro a volte cerca di romperle, come succede in musica.

Comment: Mi sembra che tu non abbia le idee molto chiare su come funziona il lavoro dei lessicografi. Ti consiglio la lettura, per un primo orientamento, di Mario Cannella, _Idee per diventare lessicografo_ (Zanichelli 2010).

Comment: @dag, se leggi con attenzione puoi notare che non sono stato del tutto negativo ("quanta autorevolezza possono avere i linguisti ... non poca"), ho soltanto sostenuto che non ci può essere affidabilità al 100% di tutto quanto dice un linguista. Tant'è vero che a volte gli studiosi sono in disaccordo, e anche senza sapere nulla, usando la logica deduco che se due persone sono in disaccordo, una delle due un po' di torto ce l'ha. O sbaglio? ...

Comment: ... Il mio pensiero non critica i linguisti, prende atto delle difficoltà insite in questa scienza e considera anche il fatto che parte del lavoro del linguista arriva a noi indirettamente tramite un'opera (es. un dizionario) che deve sottostare a regole che niente hanno da vedere con la linguistica. Un'analogia può essere l'ambiente musicale, dove a volte l'artista è costretto a scendere a compromessi: una volta più di adesso, ma sarai a conoscenza anche tu di testi cambiati per esigenze varie (principalmente censure).

Comment: Grazie per le precisazioni, ma non ho mai detto che tu sia negativo o positivo, o altro di quello che precisi. Dico soltanto che da quello che scrivi sembrerebbe che tu non abbia molta familiarità con come si svolge concretamente il lavoro di compilazione e aggiornamento di un dizionario. Magari è anche peggio di quello che pensi... :)

Comment: Per argomentare meglio, è ovvio che linguisti e lessicografi sono esseri umani fallibili come i fruttivendoli e i chirurghi. Ciò nonostante, insistere sulle eventuali motivazioni commerciali del loro lavoro e, ancor peggio, sul fatto che plagerebbero altre fonti, più ancora che essere scorretto e offensivo, denota appunto una certa ignoranza su come si svolge il loro lavoro (ripeto, imperfetto e fallibile come quello di chiunque altro).

Comment: @DaG: considera: per quanto ne sai tu io potrei essere un redattore di dizionari appena licenziato per le sue idee poco ortodosse; per quanto ne so io di te, tu potresti essere un redattore di dizionari offeso dalle mie parole. Poi: io non ho mai detto che i linguisti sono fallibili, ho detto che la materia che trattano è poco oggettiva (o, ammorbidisco, lo è meno di altre). Riguardo al copia/incolla, ritieni che la stesura di un dizionario avvenga riscrivendo tutto da zero? O ritieni che il redattore che revisiona un lemma non si prenda la briga di consultare altre fonti?

Comment: Infatti, non hai detto che sono fallibili, bensì varie cose tra cui che commettono illeciti; il mio è un eufemismo. Ti chiedo solo di informarti prima di salire in cattedra (un esempio per tutti di fraintendimento fondamentale: “qualche linguista (o redattore di dizionari...) va a pensare che il vocabolo è "italiano" perchè l'ha usato il grande e "autorevole" Umberto Eco”). Comunque, non importa ciò che ritengo io, e non mi devi convincere di niente. Buon proseguimento.

Comment: Una mia impressione è che questo testo non sia una risposta alla domanda, se non in modo piuttosto indiretto. L'altra impressione è che la classificazione “dialettismo” o “regionalismo” sia spesso una scelta del lessicografo e quindi che la domanda non abbia una vera “risposta ufficiale”. Piuttosto che argomentare in modo generico, la risposta potrebbe analizzare casi concreti da cui derivare una prova della mia seconda impressione.

Comment: @egreg ho aggiornato la risposta, senza ottemperare abbastanza alle tue raccomandazioni, ma ho cercato di spiegare anche il perché.